Optimize precision and recall for specific classes in an imbalanced classification problem
I have three classes {-1, 0, 1}. The data is in the ratio 1:20:1 on average for the corresponding classes. I want to achieve

High precision(>70%) and average recall (30%-40%) on classes -1 and 1.
High recall for class 0 (>90%). Precision for class 0 does not matter.

Misclassification on -1's and 1's are costly.
I currently have two models. Let's call the first model m1 (ensemble, trained on all three classes), and the second model m2. m1 is fitted using EasyEnsembleClassifier (from imblearn, uses XGBoost as the base model) to classify all three classes. If the prediction of m1 is -1 or 1, the data is then fed into m2 (trained as a binary classifier on -1's and 1's using XGBoost) and the prediction from m2 is then used as the final prediction. If the prediction of m1 is 0, then 0 is the final prediction.
m2 has also been calibrated. So that if there are many 0's that are being misclassified as 1's and -1's from m1, I can use m2 to set a probability threshold to filter out the wrong preds.
From the confusion matrix and the classification report below my method doesn't seem to work at all. I have already tried oversampling (SMOTE, ADASYN), undersampling and setting weights to classes (scale_pos_weight). What can I do to improve the performance of the model and increase the quality of predictions for -1 and 1. Any suggestions are welcome.



Sensitivity, specificity etc. and any weighted combinations of these suffer from all the same issues as accuracy, i.e., they all presume a very specific cost structure to decisions in the face of uncertainty - but they do not make the costs explicit. Better to work with probabilistic classifications and separate the decision aspect from them. Decisions need to take classifications and costs into account, and even if there are only two classes, there may well be more than two possible decisions

Unbalanced classes are almost certainly not a problem, and oversampling, undersampling or weighting will not solve this non-problem:
Are unbalanced datasets problematic, and (how) does oversampling (purport to) help?
And this Meta.CV thread contains a curated list of useful links on imbalanced data.

Finally, what you want to achieve, whether expressed in useful metrics or in less useful ones, may not be achievable: How to know that your machine learning problem is hopeless?

Is this confusion matrix report from training or test data? If training is good but your test result is not, are your sure your test data is not out-of-distribution (OOD)? If your training is already confused, is your data high-dimensional? For robust training with imbalanced data, you need to leverage domain knowledge like U-Net CNN for biomedical images with limited available images, you can upsample imbalanced data via rotational deformation invariance, and for your specific cost structure spec you can do selective prediction by adapting your CE loss with  your cost weights for each class.

@StephanKolassa I've read all the CV links that you mentioned in your comments. Excellent collection of threads and kudos to you, you seem to have put in a lot of effort into them. I'm glad to have learned a few things... and unlearn some too.

@StephanKolassa I'm looking for a way to make automated decisions, where no human input can be given after looking at the predicted probs. (A doc may do further tests on a patient to ensure that he is infact positive after looking at a relatively higher prediction value, ex. If the test results said there is a 0.4% chance of +ve, he is sent for further tests as opposed to 0.2%, where he may be kept under observation). Am I right in assuming that I can expect to improve the performance of the metrics I am interested in by choosing the right scoring rule. Or does the rabbit hole go even deeper?

If you want to automate the decision-making, you have to consider the costs of incorrect decisions (and upsides of correct decisions). Otherwise, there’s not much reason to believe your decisions will be desirable.

@cinch This is from the test set. I am seeing similar performances across both train and test set. I have a total of 190 features, I can't think of how I can leverage U-Nets for my use case...I am exploring new methods so a suggestion would help greatly. To address the final aspect of your comment, about weighting, do you think the weights can be hyperparameters? or should they be constants that can be defined by the class ratios?

Your comment sounds precisely like you want well-calibrated probabilistic predictions and multiple (!) thresholds. As Dave writes, these thresholds will need to be set based on costs, or whatever way you have to evaluate the goodness of your decisions. Per above, precision, recall etc. will not be helpful.

As I mentioned already to upsample you have to employ some domain knowledge like U-net since your training is already confused most likely due to very limited and imbalanced available data, and you didn't mentioned any domain background knowledge here. As for cost weights for your specific risk objective I don't see how you can make them not integrated into your objective but as hyperparameters since they're part of the objective. You can simply set them as some heuristic constants or more advance you can made a hierarchical Bayesian model to tune them based on some consolidated risk measure
